# How to avoid the http packet merging?

Tags: windows, http, go, networking, tcp

I write go codes to send Http streaming chunks:

```
func handle02(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    for {
        n, err := w.Write([]byte("h\r\n"))
        if ww,ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
             ww.Flush()
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err, n)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The client receive the chunks and print it

```
import requests

a = requests.post(url, stream=True)
for line in a.iter_lines():
    if line:
        print(line)
```

It works fine on win10 and Linux. But when I run the client on Windows server, it will merged the chunks into one packet. I use wireshark to check and find it will packet the chunks to a big packet.

[image]

But on the win10, the wireshark result is
[image]

Every flush of the sever will produce a small packet in the client. It's fine.
I have try many methods from the internet like
"disable the tcp auto tuning", "disable Nagle Algorithm"

But they don't work.
So how could I forbid the merging packet ?

Thanks

Comment: What a point of running it on windows server?

Comment: What's with the flushing and sleeping? If you want to implement the HTTP protocol, you have to actually implement the protocol. The protocol tells you where things end and begin, that's its purpose.

Comment: Actually I write a port reverse forwarding tool over HTTP. It's work fine until I run the client on the windows server to reverse forward its port to internet. So I dig out it is because the windows server host packet the http chunks from server.

Comment: Flushing is for avoiding the buffer in the sender side. It will send the message as a chunk immediately.
Sleeping is just to slow down the send process to check when the client can receive the message. Only when the client (win server) buffer full(about 4096B), the windows server will packet the chunks into one http packet and the client can receive it.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? Packet merging is a good thing, not a bad thing. Why do you think you need to fix it?

Comment: @user207421
Because in my case, I will use the HTTP chunk transfer as a message channel. I need it receive the packet immediately once the server flush it to client buffer. But the client server will buffered it until it's full. It will block my program. The server send the first message very small and wait the client response(in another http connection). It will block here forever.

Comment: Only if you don't program it correctly. Both HTTP and TCP are entitled to chunk the data any way they like. Your code has to cope with that.

Comment: @user207421 But why all other hosts(win10/linux) work fine? Just win server doesn't work. I think it's caused by some settings in win server.
As I known, when use go http flush, it will encode the current buffered content by chunked transfer encoding and send it to client. Actually all other host works fine.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't correct. You mean 'behaves differently'. No definition of TCP or HTTP is being violated here, so there is no "doesn't work" about it. If you mean why your code doesn't work, how could we say without seeing it? Of what you have posted, I will only say that there are no sleeps in correct networking code.

Comment: @user207421 sleeping is just for slow down the sending process for debug. No sleeping codes behavior same. It's not the point. My words are not very accurate, it's not the point too.I think you know what I mean and what my issues. so if you known the reason or some constructive suggestions, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml

Comment: If you want to send discrete messages, then you should use a message protocol, e.g. UDP. TCP is a stream protocol.

Comment: I don't understand how you can possibly think I know your issues when you haven't posted enough code to see them, and when you show no sign of having understood what you have already been told by me and several other people.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong approach for the job. HTTP is a protocol on top of TCP where the client sends a request and the server sends a response. There is no finer granularity in that, i.e. there is no control when to send and receive different parts of the response for a single request (HTTP chunking does not provide this granularity either).

While it might be possible by chance to  achieve a more granular control in some specific cases this granularity is hard to maintain when different OS are involved, different versions of the libraries, proxies etc - because these care only about the level granularity which is needed from the standard and not the one you want to achieve by **misusing the HTTP protocol**.

If you want to have a finer granularity you have to **use the protocol as it was designed** and not as it works for you in some specific cases. This means you either have to use multiple requests to get multiple responses instead of essentially expecting multiple responses for a single request. Or use WebSockets which allow arbitrary messages in any direction at arbitrary times. Or use TCP directly which allows this too.

EDIT: Based on the comments the client is running behind a firewall and the server is outside. It is unlikely that the problem is caused by Windows vs. Linux but more likely that this is caused by the Firewall. **The firewall likely employs a (transparent) proxy** and the OP thus runs into the problem [described in the documentation for Flusher](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher):

> ...if the client is connected through an HTTP proxy, **the buffered data may not reach the client until the response completes**

This can also be seen from the packet captures: In the successful case one can see the use of HTTP chunking, i.e. the `33 0d 0a 68 0d 0a 0d 0a` from the screenshot is a single HTTP chunk:

```
3\r\n     <<< this is the length of the chunk in hex
h\r\n     <<< this is the payload of the chunk
\r\n      <<< end of chunk
```

Contrary to this in the packet capture in the nonworking case on can see that no chunking is done, i.e. the `68 0d 0a 68 0d 0a 68 0d 0a ...` is:

```
h\r\n 
h\r\n
h\r\n
...
```

This means that the (transparent) proxy is likely reading the chunked response and forwarding it as unchunked. Such behavior is not unusual especially with proxies doing content analysis as they often do in firewalls. But it might also be that the proxy is modifying the clients request to be HTTP/1.0 in which case the server would not use HTTP chunked encoding in the first place since this is only supported with HTTP/1.1.

Comment: thanks. Actually the first version of my tool is using one response to one request. But it's too slow. So I just do an experimental misusing the HTTP protocol by the HTTP chunking, which I can keep a HTTP connection and send streaming data（like a client download a infinite size file). 
It works fine for most of my case except the win server. So I want to know the reason. Is there some settings in win server ?
WebSockets/TCP/UDP are not considered because my environment firewall forbid all connections except HTTP.

Comment: @zxt: First, you are not using HTTP chunking (i.e. `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`) but you just send a chunk of data. Can you please describe your setup in more detail, i.e. where is the server, where is the client (same or different machine as server), what is between server and client (i.e. middleboxes like firewalls or proxies or similar) and where did you do the packet capture (client side or server side).

Comment: thanks your patient. As I known when you call the http flush in Golang, it will use the chunked encoding to send the data(maybe I'm wrong, please point out). I run the server codes on a public linux server. The client runs on my win server host behind a firewall. Actually I don't know more details about the network environment of the win server. You mean the firewall can also do something like merging packet/buffer packet ?

Comment: @zxt: *"You mean the firewall can also do something like merging packet"* - it is likely a (transparent) proxy and thus you run in exactly the problem [described in the documentation for Flusher](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher): *"...if the client is connected through an HTTP proxy, the buffered data may not reach the client until the response completes."*.

Comment: thanks! I missed this statement. Could you tell me if my understanding is right "As I known when you call the http flush in Golang, it will use the chunked encoding to send the data"? I think I saw this before but can't remembered.

Comment: @zxt: The actual use of HTTP chunked encoding depends on several things, among them support in the client (i.e. HTTP/1.0 does not support it, HTTP/1.1 does). But as you can see from my updated answer the problem is not in the server but instead the proxy is modifying the traffic.